# if statement in access with multiple conditions

Tags: ms-access

I got this formula in excel I need to convert to access. I come up with this but the result will give all "accurate" result event if some are supposed to be "not accurate"

```
MRP Method Accurate:IIF([ITEM_TYPE]="PH"AND[MRP_PLANNING_CODE]="Not planned","accurate",
IIF([INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE]="SrvcOnly"OR[INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE]="Inactive"
AND[MRP_PLANNING_CODE]="Not planned","accurate",
IIF([INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE]="ContrldRel"OR[INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE]="Relsd Item"OR[INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE]="Relsd SKU"
OR[INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE]="PhsingOut"AND[MRP_PLANNING_CODE]="MRP and MPP planning","accurate",
IIF([INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE]="Unreleased"AND[ITEM_TYPE]="SA"AND[MRP_PLANNING_CODE]="MRP and MPP planning","accurate",
IIF([INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE]="Unreleased"AND[ITEM_TYPE]="PUR"AND[MRP_PLANNING_CODE]="Not planned","accurate","not accurate")))))
```

I also tried.

```
MRP Method Accurate:IIF([ITEM_TYPE]="PH"AND[MRP_PLANNING_CODE]="Not planned","accurate",
IIF([INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE] IN("SrvcOnly","Inactive")AND[MRP_PLANNING_CODE]="Not planned","accurate",
IIF([INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE] IN("ContrldRel","Relsd Item","Relsd SKU","PhsingOut")AND[MRP_PLANNING_CODE]="MRP and MPP planning","accurate",
IIF([INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE]="Unreleased"AND[ITEM_TYPE]="SA"AND[MRP_PLANNING_CODE]="MRP and MPP planning","accurate",
IIF([INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE]="Unreleased"AND[ITEM_TYPE]="PUR"AND[MRP_PLANNING_CODE]="Not planned","accurate","not accurate")))))
```

but is having the error Sytax error (missing operator) in query expression 'MRP Method Complete'.

Comment: I also tried this one.

Answer (score 0):

how about limiting your code to just one iif:

```
MRP Method Accurate:
IIF( ([ITEM_TYPE]="PH" AND [MRP_PLANNING_CODE]="Not planned")
    or ([INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE]="SrvcOnly"OR[INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE]="Inactive" AND[MRP_PLANNING_CODE]="Not planned")
    or ([INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE]="ContrldRel"OR[INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE]="Relsd Item"OR[INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE]="Relsd SKU" OR[INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE]="PhsingOut"AND[MRP_PLANNING_CODE]="MRP and MPP planning")
    or ([INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE]="Unreleased"AND[ITEM_TYPE]="SA"AND[MRP_PLANNING_CODE]="MRP and MPP planning")
    or ([INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE]="Unreleased"AND[ITEM_TYPE]="PUR"AND[MRP_PLANNING_CODE]="Not planned")
    ,"accurate"
    ,"not accurate")
```

If you want to find out which piece is passing the test then make this 5 columns.

```
    IIF( ([ITEM_TYPE]="PH" AND [MRP_PLANNING_CODE]="Not planned"),1,0)
        ,iif([INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE]="SrvcOnly"OR[INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE]="Inactive" AND[MRP_PLANNING_CODE]="Not planned"),1,0)
        ,iif([INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE]="ContrldRel"OR[INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE]="Relsd Item"OR[INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE]="Relsd SKU" ),1,0)
,iif([INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE]="PhsingOut"AND[MRP_PLANNING_CODE]="MRP and MPP planning"),1,0)
        ,iif([INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE]="Unreleased"AND[ITEM_TYPE]="SA"AND[MRP_PLANNING_CODE]="MRP and MPP planning"),1,0)
        ,iif(([INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE]="Unreleased"AND[ITEM_TYPE]="PUR"AND[MRP_PLANNING_CODE]="Not planned")),1,0)
```

Name them appropriately.

Finally add another column

```
iif(Test1+...+testN >0, "accurate","not accurate")
```

Comment: I will try. Thank you.

Comment: Still the same result all accurate.

Comment: @BudangBudang You can make more columns to see what is actually passing the test. And then make sure that piece is being done correctly. I don't know your data to provide a better solution.